# Neo4j cypher query on ID returns no values via REST but does via Data Browser

Tags: rest, neo4j

Neo4j version 1.8.M06

The following query executed in the Data Browser on the web management interface returns a value for the Forename property:

```
start n=node(*) where ID(n)=147 return n.Forename
```

However the same query posted using the REST API

```
{
  "query" :
  "start n=node(*) where ID(n)={id} return n.Forename",
  "params" : 
  {"id" : "147"}
}
```

Returns:

```
{
  "columns" : [ "n.Forename" ],
  "data" : [ ]
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: one value is integer and the second is string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want quotes around 147 in the REST call.

Also, maybe it's because of your simplification, but I'm pretty sure you should really be doing `start n=node({id})` instead, for optimum performance. Not sure if it optimizes that sort of thing out.

Comment: Thanks! Both solutions work. Can't believe I didn't think to use it as the start node!